# Updating Blob Image Field MySQL + VB.Net

Tags: mysql, database, vb.net, image, blob

If I was to insert a new blob it is easy, I have no error and it gets outputted way out from my database.

But when I try to update an existing blob in my database with a new blob .. I get an error that it is not saved, although it says that it "was" saved. I use this line to update my blob

```
Try
    MySqlConn.Open()
    MySqlQry = "UPDATE employee_information_system SET emp_idpic = @image_data WHERE emp_name = 'Master Admin';"
    MySqlComm = New MySqlCommand(MySqlQry, MySqlConn)
    MySqlComm.Parameters.AddWithValue("@image_data", imgArray)
    MySqlComm.ExecuteNonQuery()

    MsgBox("Image Saved !")
Catch ex As Exception
    MsgBox(ex.Message)
End Try
```

I hope someone can help me with this. This is MySQL in VB.Net.

Comment: Possibly `emp_name = 'Master Admin'` updates zero rows? Run the command in SSMS to check?

Comment: it only says it was saved because you have code there displaying "Image Saved !" no matter what happens

Comment: @plutonix, but shouldnt the block of codes be stopped once an error occured, the fact that the image saved message appeared is that there was nothing wrong when the app scanned through the try section of the try catch ??

Comment: the messagebox means only that no *exception* occurred; there could be logic errors such as imgArray having the same data as what is already in the db.